# How to integrate dagger2 in GWT application?

Tags: gwt, dagger-2

I am trying to add dagger2 in my gwt application to have DI. So far I have followed following steps

1) Added following dependencies in `pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>dagger-gwt</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.auto.factory</groupId>
        <artifactId>auto-factory</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-beta3</version>
    </dependency>
```

2) Inherits dagger dependency in gwt module `MyApp.gwt.xml` by adding following line of code.

```
<inherits name="dagger.Dagger" />
```

3) Created Component Class.

```
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus;
import dagger.Component;

@Singleton
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {

    EventBus eventBus();
}
```

4) Created Module class

```
import javax.inject.Singleton;

import com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus;
import com.google.gwt.event.shared.SimpleEventBus;

import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;

@Module
public class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    SimpleEventBus provideSimpleEventBus() {
        return new SimpleEventBus();
    }

    @Provides
    EventBus provideEventBus(SimpleEventBus bus) {
        return bus;
    }
}
```

Finally, when I am trying to build module in `AppEntryPoint`

```
AppComponent component = DaggerAppComponent.builder()....build();
```

I can't find generated class `DaggerAppComponent` anywhere after `mvn compile` or `mvn gwt:compile`. I am using `gwt-maven-plugin` from `org.codehaus.mojo`. Its clear I am missing something in configuration but can't figure out what exactly.

Comment: You show us `AppComponent` and say it can't find `DaggerChatComponent`....Are you mixing those 2 up?

Comment: typo, now fixed and updated.

Comment: Are any source files being generated?

Comment: nope, it was just typing mistake here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to make sure the annotation processor is triggered by the maven-compiler-plugin. I highly suggest using version 3.5.1 (at least) of the maven-compiler-plugin which fixes a number of issues that made it really impractical to use annotation processors with Maven.
With the default configuration, sources will be generated in `target/generated-sources` and added as project sources so they'll be correctly picked up by the gwt-maven-plugin later on.

You should change your `dagger-compiler` dependency to be `<optional>true</optional>` or `<scope>provided</scope>`; or even better, declare it in the `annotationProcessorPath` of the maven-compiler-plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
                <version>${dagger.gwt.version}</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

For dev mode, you'll need to re-run the annotation processor every time you make a change to the processed classes; this will generally be done by your IDE, but can be triggered from the command-line using `mvn compile` or `mvn process-classes`.

You can see a full setup in my [gwt-maven-archetypes](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes)

Comment: to have actual code snippet will be helpful for first two points. Answer  leads me to find out exact command to generate classes which is `mvn compiler:compile` or more complete `clean gwt:generateAsync compiler:compile compile`

Comment: As a rule of thumb, don't invoke direct mojos from the command-line if they're bound to a lifecycle phase in your build and/or depend on other things to have run before (e.g. generating sources). So stick with `mvn compile`, which will do `gwt:generateAsync` (bound to the `generate-sources` lifecycle phase) and `compiler:compile` (in addition to `resources:resources`), or `mvn process-classes` which will also run any mojo bound to that later lifecycle phase (which comes just after the `compile` phase). As for the code snippet, I was on mobile so couldn't easily type code (even less so XML) ;-)

Comment: It was not generating code earlier for me with simply `mvn compile` but now may be because of version `3.5.1` of `maven-compiler-plugin` or a clean before compile working for me. Thanks for reference archetype it is really helpful to solve possible future troubles :)

Comment: Can you help me with my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54048878/dagger-and-libgdx